# 10 parameter CRON TASK (IBM Maximo) workdays

Tags: cron, task, scheduled-tasks, cron-task, maximo

Can somebody explain me 10* parameter cron task? What I can find on Google only 5* parameter Cron tasks. 
Example of Cron task from the system 2d,0,0,14,*,*,*,*,*,*. (Every two days at time 14:00.)
How to get correct cron task only for workdays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have 5 Instances on the Cron Task set to run "Every 1 weeks on day (weekday) at time (whenever)"; this is the fifth option in the Set Schedule dialog. Obviously, the (weekday) would be Monday-Friday over the Instances.

If it's possible to convert the Cron Task to an Escalation, you could have it based on a Calendar that you have generated, or you could have it run every day and then use SQL in the main Escalation Condition to check whether today is a weekday/workday.

Comment: the last part about using SQL to check if 'today' is a workday might help, thank you.

Comment: For Oracle, I do time of day and day of week: `trunc(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) between 6 and 18 and to_char(sysdate, 'D') between 2 and 6` . It still runs the query, but only makes it perform during business days and hours.